# Java, Spring Security how to store JWT token in cookie

Tags: java, spring-security

I encountered a problem that when I refresh the page, my authentication fails and all cookies are erased. As I understand it, the problem is directly in my filter

Below is the filter code

### JwtRequestFilter

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private final CookieUtil cookieUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NotNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NotNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Optional.ofNullable(extractToken(request))
                .ifPresent(
                        token -> {
                            try {
                                authenticate(token, request);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                log.error(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                );
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return cookieUtil.getAccessToken(request);
    }


    private void authenticate(String token, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String email = jwtUtil.getEmailFromToken(token);

        if (email == null) {
            return;
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                jwtUtil.getRolesFromToken(token)
                        .stream()
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());


        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, authorities);
            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to add an additional auth provider for authorization, but I don't think that's the problem. If you have any ideas I would be very grateful for your help

### JwtUtil for generating token

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.jwt-lifetime}")
    private Duration jwtLifeTime;

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> rolesList = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        claims.put("roles", rolesList);
        Date issuedDate = new Date();
        Date expiredDate = new Date(issuedDate.getTime() + jwtLifeTime.toMillis());
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(issuedDate)
                .setExpiration(expiredDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
    }
    public int getMaxAge(String token)
    {
        return (int) ((getExpiration(token)-getIssued(token))/1000);
    }
    public long getIssued(String token)
    {
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).getIssuedAt().getTime();
    }

    public String getEmailFromToken(String token){
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).getSubject();
    }

    public List<String> getRolesFromToken(String token){
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).get("roles", List.class);
    }

    public Long getExpiration(String token){
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token)
                .getExpiration()
                .getTime();
    }
    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token){
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

   /* public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req){
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }*/

}
```

### CookieUtil

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class CookieUtil {

    private final String ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME = "access_token";
    private final String REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME = "refresh_token";

    public void setAccessToken(HttpServletResponse response, String token, int maxAge){
        ResponseCookie responseCookie =
                ResponseCookie.from(ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, token)
                        .path("/")
                        .maxAge(maxAge)
                        .httpOnly(true)
                        .secure(true)
                        .sameSite("None")
                        .build();
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, responseCookie.toString());
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(HttpServletResponse response, String token, int maxAge){
        ResponseCookie responseCookie =
                ResponseCookie.from(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, token)
                        .path("/")
                        .maxAge(maxAge)
                        .httpOnly(true)
                        .secure(true)
                        .sameSite("None")
                        .build();
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, responseCookie.toString());
    }

    public void clearAccessToken(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, null);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    public String getAccessToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        return Arrays.stream(cookies)
                .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals(ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME))
                .map(Cookie::getValue)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
    public void clearRefreshToken(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, null);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    public String getRefreshToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        return Arrays.stream(cookies)
                    .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME))
                    .map(Cookie::getValue)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

### AuthService

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserInstanceRepository userInstanceRepository;
    private final CookieUtil cookieUtil;

    public ResponseEntity<?> authUser(HttpServletResponse response, JwtRequestDTO jwtRequestDTO) {
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtRequestDTO.getEmail(), jwtRequestDTO.getPassword()));
            log.info(authentication.toString());
            UserInstance userInstance = (UserInstance) authentication.getPrincipal();
            log.info("User authenticated successfully: {}", jwtRequestDTO.getEmail());

            String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userInstance);
            RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createToken(userInstance.getId());

            cookieUtil.setAccessToken(response, token, jwtUtil.getMaxAge(token));
            cookieUtil.setRefreshToken(response, refreshToken.getToken(),
                    refreshTokenService.getExpiryDate(refreshToken));

            log.info("JWT token generated successfully for user: {}", jwtRequestDTO.getEmail());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponseDTO(token, refreshToken.getToken()));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new AppError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Неправильный логин или пароль"),
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(HttpServletResponse response, RegistrationDTO registrationDTO) {
        var userInstance = new UserInstance();
        Optional<Role> role = roleRepository.findById(registrationDTO.getRoleId());
        if (role.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new AppError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), "Role is empty"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        if (userInstanceRepository.findUserInstanceByEmail(registrationDTO.getEmail()).isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new AppError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "USER EXISTS"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        userInstance.setEmail(registrationDTO.getEmail());
        userInstance.setIdRole(role.get());
        userInstance.setRegistrationDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
        userInstance.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registrationDTO.getPassword()));
        userInstanceRepository.save(userInstance);

        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userInstance);
        RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createToken(userInstance.getId());

        cookieUtil.setAccessToken(response, token, jwtUtil.getMaxAge(token));
        cookieUtil.setRefreshToken(response, refreshToken.getToken(), refreshTokenService.getExpiryDate(refreshToken));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JwtResponseDTO(token, refreshToken.getToken()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> refreshToken(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String requestRefreshToken = cookieUtil.getRefreshToken(request);
        Optional<RefreshToken> optionalRefreshToken = refreshTokenService.findByToken(requestRefreshToken);
        if (optionalRefreshToken.isPresent()) {
            RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.verifyExpiration(optionalRefreshToken.get());
            UserInstance user = refreshToken.getUser();
            String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(user);
            cookieUtil.setAccessToken(response, token, jwtUtil.getMaxAge(token));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new TokenRefreshResponse(token, requestRefreshToken));
        } else {
            throw new TokenRefreshException(requestRefreshToken, "Refresh token is not in the database!");
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }

        String principal = null;

        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            principal = ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
            principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            log.info("{}", principal);
        }

        if (principal == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        try {
            SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
            log.info((String) authentication.getPrincipal());
            Long userId = userService.getUserIdByUsername(principal);
            refreshTokenService.deleteByUserId(userId);
            logoutHandler.logout(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
            // clear cookies/session
            cookieUtil.clearAccessToken(response);
            cookieUtil.clearRefreshToken(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Logout successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about how you are generating JWT token? Are you setting expiration validity for JWT token?

Comment: Yep. Added a class to the body that generates tokens

Comment: I initially had authorization through Bearer, but I would like to test it using cookies and ran into a problem that when refreshing on the frontend, all tokens are overwritten

Comment: why have you built this unsecure strange custom security solution?

Comment: If there are better suggestions and a link to the sample, I’ll be glad to see it. Because of the adequate ones that I found, this was the solution